B movie about some girls chased by men in the woods
I saw this movie like 15 years ago. The plot was something like this: some girls were traveling with a bus through some woods. I think it was a cheerleader team or something like that. They encounter some men, then a guy tries to rape a girl and the girls kill him. After his friends discover the body they go after the girls and hunt them. Both the girls and the men kill each other one by one and I think in the end only one girl is left and one man, and she kills him with a bow or something
Does anyone know the name of the movie?

Possibly Blood Games from 1990, which is also known as Baseball Bimbos in Hillbilly Hell (!!) in Australia. From the IMDb synopsis:

A team of [female] softball players get lost in the woods after their bus breaks down. They get attacked, beaten, raped and murdered by some psychotic men. The women fight back with baseball bats and bows and arrows.

They kill the son of the rednecks' leader with their bus after he tries to rape one of them, and the rest of the gang goes after them. The entire movie is currently available on Youtube. Here's the trailer:



